# Why Color.A = 255 on Color doesn't make it fully opaque?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors

I've created a custom control that displays a color spectrum.
I'm overriding the OnRender() method to draw the control with the colors.
For some reason the colors that are "calculated" (the R G B values) have some transparency, even though I'm setting the Alpha value (A) in the max possible value (255).
I've created a test window that shows some text on the background and, my control and a Border with a LinearGradient background and the text can be seen behind my control but not behind the Border, which clearly shows that my control has some transparency set. 
Any ideas why my calculated colors have transparency even though I'm setting A=255?
I appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks!

Here's my Window.xaml and my control's .cs:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:ColorBarTest.Views"
        x:Class="ColorBarTest.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="671.622" Width="720.102">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,66,0,558" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="218"><Run Text="TESTING THE OPACITY O"/><Run Text="F C"/><Run Text="OLOR BAR"/></TextBlock>
        <Views:TestRender Margin="0,65,671,0" />
        <Border Margin="100,65,671,0"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="577" Margin="105,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Magenta"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

TestRender.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ColorBarTest.Views
{
    public class TestRender : Control
    {
        private int Max = 99;
        private int Min = 1;

        private Color StartColor = Colors.Red;

        private Color EndColor = Colors.Fuchsia;

        static TestRender()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestRender), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestRender)));
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {

            for (double pixel = 0; pixel < ActualHeight; pixel++)
            {
                var value = ConvertYPixelToColorHandleValue(pixel);
                var color = CalculateRGBA(value);
                var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
                brush.Opacity = 1.0f;
                var pen = new Pen(brush, 1.0f);
                drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, pixel), new Point(ActualWidth, pixel));
                //Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", value);
            }
            var pen2 = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 5.0d);
            var pen3 = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Fuchsia), 5.0d);
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen3, new Point(0, 0), new Point(ActualWidth, 0));
            drawingContext.DrawLine(pen2, new Point(0, ActualHeight), new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight));

        }

        private float ConvertYPixelToColorHandleValue(double tickDrawY)
        {
            var pixelPercent = ((tickDrawY) / (float)ActualHeight);

            return (Max - (float)(pixelPercent * (Max - Min)));
        }


        public Color CalculateRGBA(double value)
        {
            var rate = (float)((value - Min) / (Max - Min));
            float posRate = rate - 1;
            // Interpolate the color, there will be a HSV interpolation also
            return RgbLinearInterpolate(posRate);
        }

        public Color RgbLinearInterpolate(double rate)
        {
            var nr = 1.0 - rate;
            var r = (byte)((nr * StartColor.R) + (rate * EndColor.R));
            var g = (byte)((nr * StartColor.G) + (rate * EndColor.G));
            var b = (byte)((nr * StartColor.B) + (rate * EndColor.B));

            return new Color { R = r, G = g, B = b, A = 255 };
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Color Bar Test screenshot]

Comment: What happens when you wrap your custom control in a border?

Comment: Just guessing but something might be wrong with drawing line by line with a 1 pixel pen like you do.

Comment: I don't think the Alpha channel works like that man, you're setting a percentage from 0 to 1, 1 being solid, 0 being opaque, and as example 0.5 being half opaque. Try 0 instead of 255 amigo.

Comment: @ChrisW. From [Color.A](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.a.aspx): `The sRGB alpha channel value of the color, a value between 0 and 255.` 0 is fully transparent, 255 is fully opaque. Not to be confused with the `Opacity` of e.g. a Brush, which is a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: @XAMlMAX - Thanks for your reply. I wrapped the control in a Border and it's still transparent.

Comment: @clemens thanks, I had misused the word opaque on top of it, havent had coffee yet. :/

Comment: @franssu I think there's something wrong with the color, not with the line by line approach, as I already tested in the last 4 lines of OnRender() I draw these lines with a system defined Color from the Colors class and these lines are opaque. I compared the ARGB values from my top and bottom calculated colors and they look the same as Colors.Red and Colors.Fuchsia, so I'm confused. Thanks for the input though

Comment: @dannygim Please see J.H. answer, it's correct.

Comment: @dannygim A better way of drawing such a color spectrum would perhaps be a `WriteableBitmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your OnRender, add this:

```
this.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

Or, change your xaml to this:

```
<Views:TestRender Margin="0,65,671,0" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
```

Or, you could try drawing overlapping rectangles:

```
//drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, pixel), new Point(ActualWidth, pixel));
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, pen, new Rect(new Point(0, pixel - 0.25), new Point(ActualWidth, pixel + 0.25)));
```

Comment: +1. As a side note, OP could have used [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see the problem (magnify on the control).

Comment: @franssu - Good idea. BTW, your comment is what made me think it was the anti-aliasing that was allowing the text to 'peek' through. +1 to your original comment!

Comment: J.H. Thanks so much! That worked! Thanks @franssu as well for your comments!